# Attach SQL to button in Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm a novice in ACCESS (using 2007), but am familiar with relational dbs and SQL.  I am trying to learn ACCESS on my own and want to build a form that is fairly user friendly, where it accepts data in fields on a window via textboxes. (I don't like the familiar Access format of just entering data in the datasheet mode). I then want to create a button that when clicked will insert that data into a table.  I was hoping to just attach that sql to the button, but I can't figure out how.

The original intent was to include my own SQL to it, then thought that I hd to attached an ACCESS-created query, but they seem to be just that queries, no capability to insert.

This is probably a very basic question, but did some research and can't find the answer online, so I apologize and thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK pretty simple. You'll be using VBA.

First, create your button on the form. In the properties, give it a name (I'm calling mine **cmdGo**). I also have 2 textboxes called **txtName** & **txtAge**. Then right click on the command button and select "*Build Event...*". If given a choice, select "*Event Procedure*".

Now you should be in the VBA IDE. And it should have given you this code to start:

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

End Sub
```

You'll be working inside that "procedure". You'll build and execute your SQL statement here. The syntax for an insert is

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

So, here's some sample code to get you started.

```
Private Sub cmdGO_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO AddressBook VALUES ('" & Me.txtName & "', " & Me.txtAge & ")"
   CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

This will get you started. If you look at the code, you should be able to figure out what's going on. Modify the code as required. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I had a suspicion that's where it was heading.  I'll work on that.  Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks-I got much further. I'm able to insert with a button using VBA&SQL when hard-coding values. But when I try to use the fields from my form, I'm getting an error. Here's the code:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accts (Acct_Name,  Acct_Bal)"  & _
                  "VALUES (" & Me.nm_acct & ", " & Me.amt_bal & ") "

Getting error: 'Run Time error - 3061 - Too few parameters. Expected 1'  Did some looking and said it may be my field names.  Double-checked and they seem correct. Also I would have thought it would say it's expecting 2 parms, unless I misunderstand this error.  Not sure where to go.

Comment: Not sure why the above code didn't appear with appropriate line feeds.  Sorry

Comment: Put a breakpoint {F9} after you build your SQL. Then in the immediate window on the bottom (ctrl-g if it's not showing) type "? strSQL". This will show you the SQL string that was built. You will see where the error is, and maybe what caused it. I'll check back in a few hours to see if you're still having issues.

Comment: Thanks-Got to immediate screen and get this, so seems like it's very close:

INSERT INTO (Accounts (Acct_Name, Acct_Balance)VALUES (InputfromForm, 1776.12);

'InputfromForm' is exactly what I entered on the form. I thought it may be related to try putting into text field, so changed above to put single quotes around the first value parm.  Didn't get what I wanted, but it actually stored a row but the value was the literal 'Me.nm_acct'  Damn strings - LOL! So it seems real close.  Any ideas?  I will check back later tonite.  Thanks so much.

Comment: When working with strings, they need to be quoted. I edited my sample to show you one way to quote a string (SQL accepts single quotes). Make sure the single quotes are within the double quotes. Also, numbers are not quoted. And dates have a # on either side (#6/16/13#).